# Constructing natural numbers from nothing

Tags: logic, set-theory

I found that many of us (mathematicians) try to construct natural numbers defined from the intuitive concept 'size of the set'. They take $\emptyset$, the empty set as the starting, then define and represent the size of the set $A_1=\{\emptyset\}$ as $1$, now define $2$ as the size of the set $A_2=\{\emptyset,A_1\}$ and so on.

My doubt: Can we take an absolute empty set $\emptyset$ without relating to a well defined universal set $U$?

Comment: In formal set theory, there is no "universal set". The empty set exists because in formal set theory there is an assumption that sets exist, and there is an axiom that says that if $A$ is a set, and $P$ is a property (which is a well-defined notion), then the collection of all $x\in A$ for which $P(x)$ is true is also a set. Given that a set $A$ exists, $\varnothing$ can be defined as $\{x\in A\mid x\neq x\}$. Another axiom says that two sets are equal if and only  if they have the exact same elements, which proves $\varnothing$ is unique, and well-defined.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin So without assuming the existence of a set $A$, one cannot have $\phi$, right?

Comment: If your set theory does not posit the existence of at least one set, then you can have no sets at all and your theory admits an empty model, which means it is useless. That's why all formal set theories include an axiom asserting the existence of *some* set. In ZFC, this is the Axiom of Infinity, which asserts the existence of an inductive set.

Comment: Don't use the Greek letter `\phi` for the empty set. Use either `\emptyset`, which produces $\emptyset$, or `\varnothing`, which yields $\varnothing$.

Comment: So, we have already some natural 'size', right?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "size". The numbers are not defined in terms of "size".

Comment: So one cannot define natural numbers in this way (in the question), right?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to argue. "Size" does not enter into it, and nobody I knows actually **defines** the natural numbers "in terms of size". So your premise is incorrect.

Comment: The natural numbers are not defined in terms of "size". They are defined in terms of "successor": start with the empty set; given any set $x$, the  "successor of $x$" is defined to be $x^+ = x\cup\{x\}$. A set $S$ is *inductive* if (i) it contains $\varnothing$ as an element; and (ii) whenever $x\in S$, $x^+\in S$ as well. The natural numbers are defined as the least inductive set. E.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53157/742) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/68664/742).

Comment: In set theory, the natural number $0$ is not defined as the "size" of $\varnothing$. Rather, by definition, $0=\varnothing$, and further
\begin{align}
1 &= \{0\}=\{\varnothing\} \\
2 &= \{0,1\} = \{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\} \\
3 &= \{0,1,2\}=\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\big\} \, .
\end{align}

Comment: It seems to strange to define numbers as sets, but since set theory only deals with sets (and no other kind of object), we are forced to take this approach. Even though the working mathematician certainly does not conceive of the number $3$ as $\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\}\big\}$, the above definition is accepted because from it we can derive the usual laws of arithmetic governing natural numbers. These properties of natural numbers are much more important than what they actually "are".

Comment: Put differently, we have a prior notion of what natural numbers and how they behave. However unnatural the set-theoretic definition of natural numbers might seem, the fact of the matter is that this set-theoretic definition can be used to demonstrate the artithmetic truths that we learnt as children. Therefore, the fact that the definition seems artificial turns out not to matter.

Comment: Don;t think that defining the natural numbers in terms of sets is meant to provides us with any *deeper* understanding of what the natural numbers are. Indeed, think of what is going on here as a way to *encode* natural numbers in terms of sets ... with the purpose of being able to say: "hey look, we can reduce a lot, if not all, of mathematics to sets .. that's cool!"

Comment: For complimentation, we require a universal set, right?

Comment: No complement (not compliment!) is taken in this problem, as far as I can see. But when set theorists take complements, it's with respect to some specific context-dependent set.